# In pandas how to replace certain items in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

In python 3 and pandas I have this dataframe:

```
doacoes_d_2014.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 125082 entries, 1 to 427355
Data columns (total 15 columns):
uf                            125082 non-null object
partido_eleicao               125082 non-null object
cargo                         125082 non-null object
nome_completo                 125082 non-null object
cpf                           125082 non-null object
cpf_cnpj_doador               125082 non-null object
nome_doador                   125082 non-null object
valor                         125082 non-null float64
tipo_receita                  125082 non-null object
fonte_recurso                 125082 non-null object
especie_recurso               125082 non-null object
descricao                     125082 non-null object
cpf_cnpj_doador_originario    125082 non-null object
nome_doador_originario        125082 non-null object
tipo_doador_originario        125082 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), object(14)
memory usage: 15.3+ MB
```

The column "cpf_cnpj_doador" has codes in string format always with 11 digits. For example:

```
'18286585291', '31601928220' and '06796478134'
```

I need to create a new column with the same "cpf_cnpj_doador" content, but replace the first three digits with * and the last two with *. Example:

```
'***865852**', '***019282**' and '***964781**'
```

Please, does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can using

```
df['new']='***'+df['cpf_cnpj_doador'].str[3:9]+'**'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df["cpf_cnpj_doador"] = df.cpf_cnpj_doador.apply(lambda x: '***'+str(x)[3:9]+'**')
```

Answer (score 1):

For regex based approach, you can do the following:

```
df['cpf_cnpj_doador'].str.replace(r'^(.{3})(.*?)(.{2})$', '***\\2**', regex=True)
```